# Php. Как вывести информацию с amung?

Tags: php

```
<?
  $ch = curl_init (); // инициализация
  curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_URL , "http://whos.amung.us/stats/readers/9xcraha8/");
  curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/5.0"); // каким браузером будем прикидываться
  curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 ); // вывод страницы в переменную
  $content = curl_exec($ch); // скачиваем страницу
  curl_close($ch); // закрываем соединение 

        echo $content;
?>
```

Хочу вывести ссылки www.laventanaindiscretadejulia.com, но не получается... Можно сказать этим кодом грузит все, но не то что нужно мне(.
Как решить такую задачу?

Comment: Получить данные мало, их нужно еще рапарсить. Тут помогут регулярные выражения или билиотеки парсинга HTML, что надежнее

Comment: И <? - это короткий тэг. Даным давно deprecated, если вообще не выпилено в новых версиях.

Comment: Посмотрел код страницы. JSON контейнер с ссылками можно получить с помощью запроса на http://whos.amung.us/stats/data/?izfhzx5s&k=9xcraha8&list=recents&max=1

Comment: Спасибо, дальше я сам... Очень помогло... Просто не мог найти эту фишку

Comment: Советую разобраться как формируется этот url

Comment: то есть, можно подробнее

Comment: Этот URL формирует фронтенд сейта. Нужно понимать, как из ссылки на страницу формируется ссылка на получение JSON и воссоздать это поведение в методе получения данных.

Comment: Хм, я не особо силен в этом. Можете подсказать или написать код? Если вам это не сложно конечно...

Comment: Совершенно не заинтересован в этом. Извините.

Comment: @ilyaplot, когда это короткие теги deprecated??

Comment: @vp_arth Похоже, перепутал

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете получить по некому ключу информацию в `JSON`:
Ваш Ключ : `9xcraha8`

URI : `http://whos.amung.us/stats/data/?izfkmass&k={key}&list=recents&max=1`

Это всё можно спарсить так:

```
$_key = '9xcraha8';
$_url = 'http://whos.amung.us/stats/data/?izfkmass&k={$_key}&list=recents&max=1';
$_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($_url), 1);

array_map(function ($page) {
    echo "<p>{$page['city']} - {$page['count']}</p>";
}, $_data['pages']);
```